# What is the difference between $('#div') and _$('div')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between `$` and `_$` in jQuery, and where we should use `$` and `_$`

```
_$('Set_txtDateinputBox_From')
$("#Set_drpdnAvailability")
```

Comment: *ReferenceError: _$ is not defined*... Don't use `_$` as long it is not defined. If it is defined, only use it for the same purpose if `$ === _$`. Use whatever you feel more comfortable with, although I don't see a reason to use another alias for jQuery unless `$` is used by another library. The gist is: Your question is not really answerable because you don't provide any context. For curious people: Yes, [`_$` actually does exist](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L13), but only locally inside jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

_$ isn't the standard jQuery namespace. So you'll get an error. ie. _$ isn't valid in jQuery unless you define it.

`$('#div')` is an element with id="div" and `$('div')` is a div element

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: no need to downvote here

Comment: @yes123: "no need"? I think you'll find the right to vote is ingrained into the site's mission. If you need a reason, the answer originally consisted of _only_ the second paragraph, a paragraph which is completely and utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the jquery code. It's just an internal mapping in case of overwrite so don't use it.

```
// Map over the $ in case of overwrite
_$ = window.$,
```

Comment: But it is not accesible from the outside anyway.

Comment: but when i use $("#div").appendChild(divdynamiccreated) its gives error object is null

Comment: Off topic but to append in jquery you use append and not appendChild. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/a4Py3/

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `_$` . You are not supposed to use `_$` . Jquery has been preloaded with `$` . Perhaps we will use `_$` in the case conflicts or we can rewrite the `$` to any strings other than  reserved words.